# Keyboard map for logi k380

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, logitech

I have a Logitech keyboard [k380 logi](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/keyboards/k380-multi-device.920-011135.html). On the laptop that I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I have discovered that the Logi software is not supported for Ubuntu.

1. Do we have an alternative for mapping the keys f1 until f12 on Ubuntu?
2. I want to change the left ctrl with the start left on the keyboard. I have searched on the internet but nothing has a solid response that was working. Also in this part, I would like to make some macros with new keymaps.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried settings > keyboard and gnome-tweaks keyboard and mouse settings?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. [Here](https://github.com/jergusg/k380-function-keys-conf) the solution.

Comment: I have installed Sollar is working ok, but I can not reprogram the keys f1 until f12, also I can not change the key Start into CTRL_Left.

Comment: I will try your solution Sadaharu Wakisaka and come back afterward